# Number show 1B instead of 1,000,000,000

Tags: actionscript-3

I make a game. I have life,money and damage. When life,money or damage are bigger than 1,000,000,000 i want to show 1B but if i buy something and money are<1B to show again for example 678,234,235.

Comment: Cool game, what language?  Also be careful because 32-bit numbers are only capable of showing up to 2b or 4b depending on signed/unsigned.

Comment: i write in actionscript 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `myNumber` is your number in question, I would do something like this:

```
var myNumber = 2000000000;
var result;
if (myNumber >= 1000000000)
    result = myNumber / 1000000000 + "B";
else
    result = myNumber;
```

Comment: My game is something like this: http://www.kongregate.com/games/Crovie/idle-mine  when i go back  and number is lower than 1b to show again the big number

Comment: @user3224375 then place this inside the main loop (or into a dislpaying routine that's called from within the main loop)

Comment: So only use `result` for displaying, while keeping `myNumber` as the actual value of your... value.

Comment: works good...but when myNumber is bigger than 2,147,483,647(this is max int value) what i need to do?

Comment: @user3224375 use floating point numbers instead?

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236094/what-is-the-maximum-integer-value-in-flex)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check it with an if statement? You'll have to pay special attention to what data type you are using since you are dealing with big numbers.

You can also try bit shifting the number and then doing the if statement. It's basically dividing the number to make it smaller and then doing the logical check.

Comment: Why would a large number comparison need to be preceded by bit shifting? I don't know AS3, but bit shifting coerces the number to 32 bits before shifting, which is exactly the opposite of what we want.

Comment: I had no frame of reference about this question so I was just trying to suggest different options for him. And one of those options was to avoid a large number comparison in favor of a small number comparison by shifting it.

Comment: If you feel an answer is not answerable because it's missing crucial details (such as the target language), feel free to vote to close instead of trying to answer nevertheless. But a language tag has already been given. Also, I'm not aware of _any_ language where downscaling before comparison might be useful.